Keyvault secrets or keys expiry notification
Can anybody share the PS script to fetch all the secrets or key from the multiple keyvaults from all subscriptions that are going to expire in few days like 7 or 5 days along with the resource group name in order to setup a expiry email notification for the IT admins ?

Tried some PS script but wasn't satisfied with the result.
Later created the automation account and imported the azure modules and tried to a create  a runbook with PowerShell but when I was running my PS script, I'm receiving the below error.

ps script

Error

PS script

PS
Connect-AzAccount -Environment azurecloud
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 'aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa'
$kvnames = get-azkeyvault
$NearExpirationSecrets = @()
foreach($rgitem in $kvnames)
{
$KeyVault = Get-AzKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $rgitem.resourcegroupname -VaultName $rgitem.vaultname
foreach ($kvitem in $keyvault)
{
$secrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $kvitem.VaultName
$7Days = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(7) -Format yyyyMMdd
$1Days = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(1) -Format yyyyMMdd
        $CurrentDate = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd


            foreach($secret in $secrets){
                if($secret.Expires) {
                $secretExpiration = Get-Date $secret.Expires -Format yyyyMMdd
                if($secretExpiration -lt $currentDate)
                    {
                        $NearExpirationSecrets += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                    Name           = $secret.Name;
                                    Category       = 'SecretExpired';
                                    KeyVaultName   = $KeyVault.VaultName;
                                    ExpirationDate = $secret.Expires;
                                }
                    }  

                    elseif($secretExpiration -le $7Days -and $secretexpiration -gt $1Days)
                    {
                        $NearExpirationSecrets += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                    Name           = $secret.Name;
                                    Category       = '1-7DaySecretExpiry';
                                    KeyVaultName   = $KeyVault.VaultName;
                                    ExpirationDate = $secret.Expires;
                                }
                    }                      
            }
    }
}

}
$NearExpirationSecrets | Sort-Object  expirationdate, category

can you share your script and why you are not satisfy with it ?

pasting the script is better than image btw

try to use Connect-AzAccount -Identity or  Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential to avoid user interaction. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-12.4.0

Please share the script in text format.

Are you excepting the output like this

If there are any better way to achieve the result, please suggest me

Do you mean the provided output is not excepted result?

FYI and as an alternative to scripting, you can use Logic Apps to receive email about status changes of key vault secrets.


I have created the automation account with module import.
I have created a runbook and ran a code and it was successful and later I published the runbook.

How can I create a email notification to IT admins email every day to get that runbook or powershell script output ?


Keyvault secrets or keys expiry notification

Here is the updated PowerShell script to fetch all key vault secrets with expiry date and displayed which secrets are going to expire in 7 days.

Note: Make that your automation account identity has the Key Vault Administrator role on all your subscriptions. In my case I use automation Identity.

Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$allsub = Get-AzSubscription
$expiringSecrets = @()

$todaydate = Get-Date

foreach ($subscription in $allsub) {
    
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id
    
   $allkeyvault = Get-AzKeyVault
    
    foreach ($keyVault in$allkeyvault) {
     
        
        $keyvaultsecrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVault.VaultName | Select-Object VaultName, Name, Expires

        foreach ($secret in $keyvaultsecrets) {
            
            if ($secret.Expires) {
                try {
                    
                    $secretexpirydate = [datetime]$secret.Expires
                    $pendingdays = ($secretexpirydate - $todaydate).Days
                    
                    
                    if ($pendingdays -le 7 -and $pendingdays -ge 0) {
                        Write-Output "Secret '$($secret.Name)' in Vault '$($keyVault.VaultName)' is going to expire within 7 days, Expiration Date: $secretexpirydate."
                    } elseif ($pendingdays -gt 7) {
                        Write-Output "Secret '$($secret.Name)' in Vault '$($keyVault.VaultName)' is not expiring within the next 7 days. Expiration Date: $secretexpirydate."
                    } else {
                        Write-Output "Secret '$($secret.Name)' in Vault '$($keyVault.VaultName)' has already expired or is expired. Expired on $secretexpirydate."
                    }
                } catch {
                    Write-Output "Invalid expiry date format for secret '$($secret.Name)' in Vault '$($keyVault.VaultName)'."
                }
            } else {
                Write-Output "No Expiry Date: Secret '$($secret.Name)' in Vault '$($keyVault.VaultName)' does not have an expiration date set."
            }
        }
    }
}

Key vault Secrets

Output




I set up the automation account and imported the necessary modules.


I created a runbook, executed a PowerShell script successfully, and then published the runbook.


What steps should I take to send a daily email notification to the IT admins with the output of that runbook or PowerShell script?

Will you be able to retrieve the secrets that will expire in 7 days?

Yeah I was able to retrieve the secrets and keys along with RG through PS script but how can I create a email notification to IT admins email every day to get that runbook or PowerShell script output ?
